# for i in `cat file` give variable with space

Tags: linux, bash

I am using

```
for i in `cat file`
```

to write a loop. However, in the file, the data will be:

```
A X 
B Y
C Z
```

Is that possible I can give variable $i as:

```
$i = A X
$i = B Y
$i = C Z
```

This loop below will only give me variable splited by each space.

```
for i in `cat file` ; do
echo $i    
done;
```

Comment: Don't ever do `for i in \`cat file\``. Use `while read` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is covered by [Bash FAQ 001](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001); don't use a `for` loop for this.

```
while IFS= read -r i; do
    echo "$i"
done < file
```

`read` ensures you get a full line of text from the file to assign to `i`; quoting `$i` ensures that you reproduce the value exactly.

Comment: Don't use `echo` for this - it fails if, for instance, the line starts with `-n` or `-e`.  Use `printf '%s\n' "$i"` instead.

Comment: True; I assumed here that `echo` was just a stand in for "do something with `i`".